# Dispatch Group not allowing Alamofire request to execute

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using DispatchGroup to wait until a callback for one of my functions executes before continuing. Within that function, I'm calling Alamo fire get request. My issue occurs when I introduce the DispatchGroup, the AlamoFire closure never gets executed.

Sample

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
Networking.getInfo(userID: userID) { info in
    group.leave()
}

group.wait()
```

`Networking` class:

```
static func getInfo(userID: Int, completion: @escaping(_ info: String) -> Void) {
    // Program reaches here
    Alamofire.request("https://someurl.com").responseJSON { response in
        // Program does NOT get here
        if let json = response.result.value {
            completion("Successful request")
        } else {
            completion("Some Error")
        }
    }
}
```

When I don't use the DispatchGroup, it works fine. When I DO use the DispatchGroup, The `getInfo` function starts, but the closure of the Alamofire request never gets executed.

Comment: Trying to turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one is the wrong approach.

Comment: Dispatch group is not a choice to wait until operation finished. You might need Semaphore . But with that you might get in deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm right, but I suspect that the Alamofire response is being queued on the same queue (main) that the group has suspended (wait()). Because the queue is suspended, the completion closure never executes.

Manually writing asynchronous code like this can be quite tricky. My suggestion would be to use any one of the asynchronous libraries out there which can help with this. My personal favourite being [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) which also has specific extensions to support Alamofire. Projects like this can take a lot of the headache out of asynchronous code. They may take some time to get your head around their paradigms, but it's worth doing.

Comment: I think you may be correct. I switched `group.wait()` to `group.notify(queue: .main){.....}` with the dependent code in the closure and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In that case I used URLSession request to get ride of it. This API enables your app to perform background downloads when your app isn’t running or, in iOS, while your app is suspended.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession

```
let request = try URLRequest(url: url, method: .get, headers: headers)
Alamofire.request(request) { response in
    ...
    ...
}
```

I changed it like this :-

```
let request = try URLRequest(url: url, method: .get, headers: headers)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    ...
    ...
}
task.resume()
```

And then it worked fine.